# Referring to something in the last sentence with "This"

Tags: grammar, antecedents

Is it clear what **"This"** refers in the following text?

> When someone runs out of ideas and reaches an impasse, they should
> confer to an experienced consultant. This is the key to break the
> deadlock and achieve a significant breakthrough.

I wonder if it is clear or not? With "**this**" at the first of the second sentence, I wanted to refer to the whole idea of conferring an experienced consultant.

Answer (score 1):

'*This*' is correct but I would not use '*confer*' in this instance. In the example cited [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/confer), confer is used in the much stronger sense of reaching a decision and would be used alongside '*with*' ordinarily if not always.

Your passage might read better as the following:

> When someone runs out of ideas and reaches an impasse, they should `converse / meet/ speak` with an experienced consultant. This is the key to `breaking` deadlock and `achieving` a significant breakthrough.